# Build Qt 5.1 statically

Tags: c++, qt, static

I am trying to compile the Qt 5.1 source to be able to do static linking.
my configuration is:

```
configure -static -release -platform win32-msvc2010 -nomake tests -nomake examples -opengl desktop
```

The problem is that the build fails with error saying that Qt5v8.lib does not exist.

```
        cd qml\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt5.1\5.1.0\msvc2010_static\qtbase
\bin\qmake C:\Qt5.1\5.1.0\msvc2010_static\qtdeclarative\src\qml\qml.pro -o Makef
ile ) && C:\Qt5.1\5.1.0\msvc2010_static\jom.exe -f Makefile
        C:\Qt5.1\5.1.0\msvc2010_static\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release
Error: dependent 'C:\Qt5.1\5.1.0\msvc2010_static\qtbase\lib\Qt5V8.lib' does not
exist.
jom: C:\Qt5.1\5.1.0\msvc2010_static\qtdeclarative\src\qml\Makefile [release] Err
or 2
jom: C:\Qt5.1\5.1.0\msvc2010_static\qtdeclarative\src\Makefile [sub-qml-make_fir
st-ordered] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt5.1\5.1.0\msvc2010_static\qtdeclarative\Makefile [sub-src-make_first]
Error 2
jom: C:\Qt5.1\5.1.0\msvc2010_static\Makefile [module-qtdeclarative-make_first] E
rror 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what i did as a temporary solution, I copied the file `Qt5v8.lib` from the pre compiled Qt package and put it in `\qtbas\lib` and then ran the jom command again it compiled successfully.

Comment: I did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I built Qt 5.1 with these configs and it's working fine for me .

```
configure -release -platform win32-msvc2012  -nomake demos -nomake examples -nomake tests -opengl desktop -qt-sql-sqlite -audio-backend -static -opensource -ltcg
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried the same configuration but it doesn't work, except my platform is win32-msvc2010, I also tried win32-g++ and used minGW32 compiler.